# django blog no display - beginner

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views, django-urls

I am running django 1.4.6 with python 2.7 and I am trying to get a test blog working to help my coding skills - but I have run into some trouble and now I am very confused, so I must ask for some help.

Here is my model.py entry:

```
class BlogPostDetails(models.Model, FillableModelWithLanguageVersion):
    blog_post_title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
blog_post_date_published = models.DateTimeField()
blog_post_author = models.CharField(max_length=50)
blog_post_body = models.TextField()
blog_post_timestamp_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
blog_post_timestamp_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.blog_post_title
```

Here is my url.py entry:

```
    url(r'^details/blog_list/$', 'blog_post_list', name='blog_post_list'),
```

Here is my views.py entry:

```
def blog_post_list(request):
    language_versions = get_language_versions(user=request.user)
    blog_posts = BlogPostDetails.objects.filter()
    return render(request, 'core/details/blog_list.html', {
        'display_default_language': display_default_language(request.user),
        'languages': LANGUAGES,
        'language_versions': language_versions,
        'language_versions_num': len(language_versions),
        'popover_string_length_20': settings.POPOVER_STRING_LENGTH_20,
        'popover_string_length_500': settings.POPOVER_STRING_LENGTH_500,
    })
```

Here is my template loop where I thought the blog details would be displayed:

```
{% block page_content %}
    {% for blog_post in blog_posts %}
        {{ forloop.counter }}<br />
        {{ blog_posts.blog_post_body|safe|truncatechars:popover_string_length_500|linebreaksbr }} <br />
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

I have added the blog to the admin and added several blog records.

**My problem is what have I done incorrectly because nothing is showing in the template. I really need some guidance here.**

Comment: You wrote `blog_posts.blog_post_body`. I think you meant `blog_post` (singular).

Comment: Please don't prefix all your field names with the name of the class. It's unnecessary duplication.

Comment: Daniel Roseman - I use the prefix for my own reference. It makes the reading of the code easier for me personally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't appended blog_posts to your context at your view:

```
def blog_post_list(request):
    language_versions = get_language_versions(user=request.user)
    blog_posts = BlogPostDetails.objects.filter()
    return render(request, 'core/details/blog_list.html', {
        'blog_posts': blog_posts, # HERE YOU GO
        'display_default_language': display_default_language(request.user),
        'languages': LANGUAGES,
        'language_versions': language_versions,
        'language_versions_num': len(language_versions),
        'popover_string_length_20': settings.POPOVER_STRING_LENGTH_20,
        'popover_string_length_500': settings.POPOVER_STRING_LENGTH_500,
    })
```

Comment: Thank you. I was suffering from information overload, so I didn't see the error.